# URL amigable con .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, xampp, mod-rewrite

la cuestión es que estoy realizando un acortador de links desde cero, el acortador ya realiza su función y demás, pero ahora mi problema es cómo poder hacer el la dirección `URl` más amigable, ya que actualmente la dirección es: `http://localhost/ad/index.php?id=111111`, mi idea sería poder pasar a que sea simplemente: `http://localhost/ad/111111`.

He probado varias **expresiones regulares** de las cuales mucho no entiendo, pero ninguna me ha dado resultados. No está de más está decir que, sí, está activado `mod_rewrite` en **apache**.

Actualmente mi código es este:

**.htaccess**

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Manejo de encabezado de autorización
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirigir barras diagonales finales si no es una carpeta
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Controlador Frontal
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^index.php?id=(.+)$ /adroll/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
</IfModule>

<Files .htaccess>
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Quien me pudiese aportar una solución o información, estaré más que agradecido. Saludos.-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solución

Entiendo que el .htaccess lo tienes en el directorio raiz. Si es así, la rule debe ser al reves.

En lugar de:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php?id=(.+)$ /adroll/$1 [R=301,L]
```

deberia ser:

```
RewriteRule ^ad/(.*)$ /ad/index.php?id=$1
```

Con eso conseguiras que:

```
http://localhost/ad/111111
```

sea redirigido a

```
http://localhost/ad/index.php?id=111111
```

pero ojo, porque también

```
http://localhost/ad/11111/1111
```

seria interpretado como

```
http://localhost/ad/index.php?id=11111/1111
```

Las rules que pones antes sobre **Redirigir barras diagonales finales** no se si son correctas, a mi no me lo parecen, no se que pretendes con ellas.

Te sobra el `R=301,` al final de la linea tambien. Puede causar problemas en los navegadores de los visitantes, pues reciben esa cabecera `http` y son guardadas en su cache, y luego son redirigidos a la URL por la que tu pones, es decir, por `http://localhost/ad/index.php?id=111111`, perdiendo todo el sentido al acortamiento.

La próxima vez que visiten esa URL acortada *ni tan siquiera lo intentaran*, sino que **recuperaran el 301 del cache**. Quizás por eso tus pruebas salen mal. Límpiate la cache y quita el 301 para que no te vuelva a pasar.

Puedes dejar el `[L]` si quieres, aunque no lo veo necesario si no hay mas rules.

### **Recomendación**

Deja el `.htaccess` así, para que `index.php` haga todo el trabajo:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$   index.php [L]
```

Y luego, dentro del `index.php` recupera la url completa así:

```
$url_corta   = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 1);
```

Y a partir de ahi haz todos los filtros necesarios para comprobar si es correcta y si lo es los reenvias con esto:

```
header("X-Robots-Tag: noindex, nofollow", true);
header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
header('Cache-Control: no-cache');
header('Cache-Control: no-store');
header('Location:'.$url_destino);
die();
```

Con eso intentarás que:

1. No se guarden en google, para evitar duplicidad de páginas y pérdida de SEO de las páginas destino si google indexara tus acortamientos
2. Los navegadores no guarden el 301 en su cache, por si lo modificas y para que siempre que usen el acortador tengan que pasar por tu servidor, y así contar correctamente las veces que lo han usado (sino no te enterarás pues su cache los redigiria directamente sin pasar por tu servidor).

Comment: Muy agradecido, gracias por tu tiempo.